# Best CMS for university/college?

Tags: php, cms

Is there CMS for university or college.for these services(Register Collegian,Course Unit Selection,Exam Results,...).With PHP support!

Tnx.

Answer (score 5):

What you're describing isn't really a CMS, but rather features of a [Student Information System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_information_system). These are usually fairly complex enterprise-level applications (the academic equivalent of a CRM + ERP) that have to integrate with the school's intranet systems, government databases (e.g. financial aid databases) and meet stringent regulations regarding privacy/security and accessibility.

Vendors of SIS platforms will likely help you integrate the system into whatever CMS you're using, or they may come with their own CMS. What's "best" depends on your requirements, budget, and what other systems the school is using for managing student information.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try out [Moodle](http://moodle.org/). It allows one to create courses, and teachers can administrate individual classes under each course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a ready-made script, i would search on some joomla / drupal extensions.

Maybe http://hotscripts.com is the place to take into account also. But you will get always some sucky scripts out there unless you do it yourself.

I strongly recommend picking drupal as your solution, and making it yourself. It is a widely used CMS and easy to learn.

hope it helps.

Comment: very tnx.i using drupal in my site.but i wand know your strategy for build Student Information System with Drupal.What's your ideas?

Comment: If you are asking for the site functionality design, thats something you have to think of. I would go with something like making the user to choose a course after registering and then it is all about user permissions, you get in touch with other users who are in the same course, via a message board or private messages and maybe a private page for seeing your exam results...